# How to use execv with a generated path in C?

Tags: c, bash, shell, unix, malloc

I have an assignment wherein we have to create a shell. Part of that includes using generating paths to different unix commands. (example: /bash/ls). Using execv, I can get everything to work if I hardcode the path, but not if I generate it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/syscall.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void command(char *args[]);

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    //get the command and arguments
    char buffer[32];
    char *b = buffer;
    size_t bufferSize = 32;
    int counter = 0;
    char *tokens[10];
    char *delims = " \t\n";

    printf("dash> ");
    getline(&b, &bufferSize, stdin);

    tokens[0] = strtok(buffer, delims);

    while (tokens[counter] != NULL) {
        counter++;
        tokens[counter] = strtok(NULL, delims);
    }
    command(tokens);

}

void command(char *args[]) {
    //create path
    char *path = NULL;
    int length = strlen(args[0]);
    path = malloc(5 + length + 1);
    strcat(path, "/bin/");
    strcat(path, args[0]);

    char *input[2];
    input[0] = malloc(512);
    strcpy(input[0], path);
    printf(input[0]); //the path prints out properly
    //input[0] = "/bin/ls"; <--- this works!
    input[1] = NULL;

    //start execv
    pid_t pid;
    pid = fork();
    if(pid < 0) {
        printf("ERROR: fork failed.");
        exit(0);
    }
    else if (pid == 0) {
        execv(input[0], input);
        printf("error.");
    }

    free(path);
    free(input[0]);

}
```

anyone have any ideas? i'm pretty sure its an issue with malloc, but i'm not sure how to circumvent that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem with `getline()` since you are reading form `stdin`, this

```
getline(&b, &bufferSize, stdin);
```

store new line `\n` char at the end of `buffer` & when you pass `tokens` to `command()` function, `args` will be `ls\n` instead of `ls` which is why `execv` failed with

> execv: No such file or directory

So remove that extra `\n` character to parse `tokens` correctly, for e.g

```
ssize_t read;
read = getline(&b, &bufferSize, stdin); /* always check the return value */
if(read != -1 ) {
   b[read-1] = '\0'; /* replace \n with \0 */
}
```

Comment: Since the original code is using `strtok()`, it would be possible to add newline to the delimiter list in `strtok()` too — and tab.

Comment: after adding "\t\n" to the delimiters it worked. The changes on my original code reflect that. thanks guys!